# Out of memory exception XImage.FromFile(filePath)

Tags: c#, export-to-pdf

I'll get the Out of memory exception on the first row.

```
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(filePath);
gfx.DrawImage(image, pagePadding, pagePadding + beginDrawYPoint, imageWidth, imageHeight);
gfx.Dispose();
```

I have no idea where to look for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Your file could be too large?

Comment: What is the size of the file? What is the value of *filePath* when you get that exception? Maybe you're passing some odd value there by mistake?

Comment: the filepath is C:\\Users\\Daniel_2\\Documents\\Avtryck\\Avtryck-Base.Prod\\AvtryX.Web\\Temp SVG Files\\myfile.pdf

and the size is 0kb. 

When i go to that map and try to open it i says that the filetype is not supported or the file is damaged.

Comment: This might be causing the memory exception. Do you have any valid files like this one?

Comment: I have figured out that it has something to do with my Kendo Graph. I am drawing a image of a kendograph to my pdf. Something is wrong with it :P

Answer (score 0):

I just hit on this problem too, my solution was to change image.svg to image.png, solved the problem for me.

```
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(@"wwwroot\icons\122.png");
gfx.DrawImage(image, 250, 250, 100, 25);
```